# hdparm -S not working as it should

Tags: linux, hdparm

I have a server running Debian 8 with four 2TB-disks in RAID5 (mdadm). Since the server is used only occasionally, I've used "hdparm -S 244 /dev/sdX" for all drives which will make them spin down after two hours. This works as expected.

Recently I upgraded my server to a new one, containing five 3TB-disks (WD Purple). Using "hdparm -S 244 /dev/sdX" on these as well tells me that the disks will be spun down after two hours. However, I have reasons to believe that the don't spin down: accessing the RAID-set takes no time at all, comparing to the old server which took about 15 seconds to spin up all the drives.

Running `smartctl -i -n standby /dev/sdX` on the old server told me that all the drives are spun down. Doing the same on the new server tells me that the drives are Active/idle, i.e. not spun down despite not having been used for three days.

Why won't the drives spin down? I cannot find any hints in /var/log/messages, dmesg or similar.